# Widevine License Response with "invalid_license_challenge" internal_status=106. what does 106 stand for?

Tags: widevine

We got a failure in our Widevine license request. The response is below:

```json
[
   {
      "status":"INVALID_LICENSE_CHALLENGE",
      "supported_tracks":[
         
      ],
      "internal_status":106,
      "client_info":[
         
      ],
      "content_owner":"xxx",
      "content_provider":"xxx",
      "service_version_info":{
         "license_sdk_version":"16.4.2 Built on Feb 16 2021 15:15:05 (1613517266)",
         "license_service_version":"widevine_license_wls_20210210_101970-RC02"
      }
   }
]
```

I just couldn't find the definition for 106 anywhere on the Internet.